# ¿Cómo podría filtrar los nombres de usuarios que tengan dos vocales seguidas en Excel?

Tags: excel

Tengo un listado de nombres como estos por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son los usuarios de la API jsonplaceholder.

Necesito crear una fórmula que identifique con VERDADERO o FALSO aquellos nombres que contienen al menos dos vocales consecutivas. Por ejemplo, Leanne Graham dispone del grupo "ea", por tanto sería válido. En el caso de Ervin Howell no, pero Clementine Bauch sí ya que contiene el grupo "au" en el apellido. Yo he creado esta, y aunque es más rápida que otras alternativas que generé, aún así es posible que se puede crear algo más rápido y corto. A mí no se me ocurre y me parece que mi propuesta no es muy eficaz, aunque la he probado con 200K registros y tardó apenas 5" en devolverme el resultado. Me gustaría poder reducir ese tiempo con una fórmula más eficaz. ¿Alguna propuesta?

```
=CONTAR(
COINCIDIR(
    EXTRAE(
        A1;
        SI(
            COINCIDIR(
                EXTRAE(
                    A1;
                    SECUENCIA(LARGO(A1));
                    1
                );
                {"A"; "E"; "I"; "O"; "U"};
                0
            ) > 0;
            SECUENCIA(LARGO(A1))
        ) + 1;
        1
    );
    {"A"; "E"; "I"; "O"; "U"};
    0
)
) > 0
```

Si es posible, evitar usar fórmulas de 365 mejor.

Gracias.

Añado los usuarios para que los podáis copiar.

```
Leanne Graham
Ervin Howell
Clementine Bauch
Patricia Lebsack
Chelsey Dietrich
Mrs. Dennis Schulist
Kurtis Weissnat
Nicholas Runolfsdottir V
Glenna Reichert
Clementina DuBuque
```

Comment: Podrias usar caracteres comodin o utilizar buscarv

Comment: ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: *Me gustaría poder reducir ese tiempo con una fórmula más eficaz.* Creo que no vas a poder bajar mucho más, ya que tienes un gran volumen de datos. En cualquier caso puedes usar CONTAR.SI en formulación matricial para lo que deseas. Te pondría un ejemplo pero tus datos son una imagen y no se puede copiar y pegar

Comment: Hola Esei, he editado la consulta y añadido los nombres de los usuarios para que puedas publicar tu propuesta. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras: o basándote en una tabla externa con todas las combinaciones posibles de vocales o metiéndolas a pelo en la fórmula. En ambos casos la fórmula es la misma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula de la columna B es basándose en la tabla que hay a la derecha:

```
=SUMA(CONTAR.SI(A1;$F$1:$J$5))>0
```

La fórmula de la columna C es sin tabla auxiliar y está metida a pelo en la fórmula:

```
=SUMA(CONTAR.SI(A1;{"*aa*";"*ea*";"*ia*";"*oa*";"*ua*";"*ae*";"*ee*";"*ie*";"*oe*";"*ue*";"*ai*";"*ei*";"*ii*";"*oi*";"*ui*";"*ao*";"*eo*";"*io*";"*oo*";"*uo*";"*au*";"*eu*";"*iu*";"*ou*";"*uu*"}))>0
```

CONTAR.SI nos permite verificar si un rango de celdas (inclusive una única celda) cumple una condición o no. La condición es **que contenga** una pareja de vocales. Para contar esa condición, la pareja de vocales se mete entre asteriscos (carácteres comodín).

Por otro lado, por defecto CONTAR.SI solo permite comprar una única condición, pero en formulación matricial (usando las llaves `{ }`
) sí permite especificar más de una condición como operador O

Es decir, por ejemplo, si resumimos la fórmula a `=CONTAR.SI(A1;{"*aa*";"*ea*";"*ia*"})` básicamente le estamos pidiendo a Excel que cuente si la celda A1 **contiene** las vocales `aa` **o** si contiene `ea` **o** si contiene `ia` y así sucesivamente.

Por cada vez que se cumple la condición, se suma un 1 así que por eso el CONTAR.SI está dentro de SUMA, para saber el resultado total. A ti te da igual saber si hay 1 o más parejas, conque tenga una ya quieres que devuelva VERDADERO y por eso la formula de SUMA se chequea si es mayor que cero `>0` Si se cumple es que al menos hay una pareja de vocales. Si la suma es cero no hay ninguna y devuelve `Falso`

Importante, fíjate que con el último valor, `Clementina DuBuque` como contiene `ue` devuelve VERDADERO. Tendrás que meditar si eso te interesa o no e ir ajustando la fórmula adecuadamente.

También es posible que en versiones anteriores de Excel tengas que meter la fórmula como matricial, así que confírmala presionando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Gracias Esei, el problema que tiene tu fórmula con respecto a la que yo planteé, es que es doble de lenta. Tiene lógica teniendo en cuenta la cantidad de comparaciones que tiene que hacer. No obstante gracias por tu propuesta ya que me has aportado un concepto que me ha servido para refactorizar mi propia fórmula.